# Symfomy2 get url parameter in routing condition

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations, conditional-statements

I am trying to set up the following route

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/api/list/{setName}/{order}",
 *      condition= "request.get('order') == 'something' "
 *
 * )
 */
```

but I can only produce 404s because the condition is never true although I pass in an order argument. I guess the "request.get('order')" part is wrong, but how to do it?

Comment: Hi @Pony Tylor check my lastest answer to your question, the solution with the condition is not working fine (I try to investigate more before remove it)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
       condition= "request.query.get('order') == 'something' "
```

instead of

```
       condition= "request.get('order') == 'something' "
```

check more help [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#completely-customized-route-matching-with-conditions) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#component-http-foundation-request)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Routing docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#completely-customized-route-matching-with-conditions) with conditions, I don't find any reference to an annotation definition for route conditions. You should probably use another format.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the `requirements` attribute as follow:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/api/list/{setName}/{order}",
 *       requirements={"order":"something"}"
 *
 * )
 */
```

Hope this help