# Routing condition with parameter in Symfony

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

I have a route with a parameter `{id}` on which I want to apply a condition. Only if `{id}` contains more than 3 characters, this route should be available. I read about conditions in routes both [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html) and in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201464/symfomy2-get-url-parameter-in-routing-condition). What I tried:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="some_route", condition="strlen(id) > 3")
 */
```

I also tried with `requirements` instead of `condition` and tried `{id}` instead of `id`. No luck. The error that is show is:

> The function "strlen" does not exist around position 1 for expression `strlen(id) > 3`.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Try with regex. Add requirements as [requirements={"id"="[0-9]{3}"}]

Answer (score 2):

In this case, using `regular expression` is the best option. Take a look in the PHP documentation to find out more (Here is [the link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)). And suppose the characters you are referring to are alphanumeric characters (I added the `-` and `_`).

```php
<?php

// some code ...

/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="some_route", requirements={"id"="[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,}"})
 */
```